# Create custom dialog box in ionic 2

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, ionic-view

I want to create custom dialog box in `ionic2`. I have tried lot's of reference [ionic docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/alert/AlertController/) tutorial but I am not getting what I want.

I want to show this when user click on icon.
[image]

Please give me some idea to achieve the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use an ionic modal with a custom class name,so you override the css only for this popup

to open the popup:

```
openModal() {
   let modal = this.modalCtrl.create(CustomPopup,{},{showBackdrop:true, enableBackdropDismiss:true});
   modal.present();
 }
```

component used in modal:

```
import { Component, Renderer } from '@angular/core';
import {   ViewController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'custom-popup',
  templateUrl: 'custom-popup.html'
})
export class CustomPopup {

  text: string;

  constructor(public renderer: Renderer, public viewCtrl: ViewController) {
    this.renderer.setElementClass(viewCtrl.pageRef().nativeElement, 'custom-popup', true);

  }

}
```

and finaly the SCSS:

```
ion-modal.custom-popup ion-backdrop {
    visibility: visible !important;
    z-index:0;
}
ion-modal.custom-popup .modal-wrapper{
    top: 20%;
    width:60%;
    height:300px;
    position:absolute;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering this question, i am getting some problem on =>where you have create modalCtrl

Comment: Now i have achieve what i want . you are savior for me thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

You can add create custom controller as below -

```
import { AlertController } from 'ionic-angular';

constructor(private alertCtrl: AlertController) {

}

presentAlert() {
  let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
    title: 'Low battery',
    subTitle: '10% of battery remaining',
    cssClass: 'my-class',
    buttons: ['Dismiss']
  });
  alert.present();
}

<style>
.my-class{
 background: gray;
 color:#333;
 }
</style>
```

On the same way  you can add your custom style. You can get complete example on - https://www.tutorialsplane.com/ionic-popup